# How can I create get location point

Tags: java, android, xml

I need to check whether certain points on an imageView are clicked in Android. I can create a button on the ImageView and get its shape, but how can I take the coordinates of the clicked area on the screen and do the action?

I am sharing an example picture with you. Action will be taken when clicking on the red areas in the sample image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For getting touch points on click you need to set touch listener and store points where you touch, don't forget to return false else wise your click listener not work on it. You also can user this extension with interface.

```
interface OnClickListener {
    fun onClick(view: View, point: PointF)
}

fun ImageView.onClickListener(clickListener: OnClickListener) {

    val touchCoordinate = PointF()

    setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
        // for getting global point use event.rawX and rawY
        touchCoordinate.x = event.x
        touchCoordinate.y = event.y
        return@setOnTouchListener false
    }

    setOnClickListener {
        clickListener.onClick(it, touchCoordinate)
    }
}
```